# Change snake_case to camelCase

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Currently, the scenario is that the data coming from the Nodejs backend is in snake_case but the frontend is using camelCase.
I am using [snakeize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/snakeize) and [camelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/camelize) to convert casing but with a compromise.

**Problem**

ObjectId `_id` using camelize is converted to `Id` while I am expecting as `id`.

**Expectation**.

`_id` must to converted to `id`

Comment: Is this just for `_id` by itself? Or is it part of something larger, like `order_id`?

Comment: just for ```_id```

Comment: ```order_id``` works as expected like ```orderId```

Comment: guess you will have to do it manually

Comment: Camelize and snakeize are both mit licensed. Their code is extremely short. You could copy paste and adapt them.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the package you're using removes every underscore he finds and converts the letter after it to upper case.
You just need to check if the first letter is underscore and remove it:

```
const obj = { "_id" : 12345678, "name" : "John Doe" };
for (let key in obj){
    if (key[0] === "_"){
        const newKey = key.slice(1);
        obj[newKey] = obj[key];
        delete obj[key];
    }
}

console.log(obj)
```

**Edit:**
Recursive:

```
const obj = { "_id" : 12345678, "name" : "John Doe", "inner_obj" : { "_id" : 12345678 } };

function removeUnderscore(obj){
    for (let key in obj){
        let newKey = key;
        if (key[0] === "_"){
            newKey = key.slice(1);
            obj[newKey] = obj[key];
            delete obj[key];
        }
        if (typeof obj[newKey] === "object" && !Array.isArray(obj[newKey])) removeUnderscore(obj[newKey])
    }
}

removeUnderscore(obj);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This fails to recursively transform the json.

Comment: what about this one ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be hard to discern your architecture or data flow from the statement above.

But I would say your current approach of reformatting the entire data structure to either be snake or camel as unnecessary. unless this data structure is being passed through functions and you have no control how it's retreated.

Reformatting the data structure requires a recursive loop. your time and complexity will increase as the data structure grows in size and nesting.

I would suggest that you create a function that wraps lo-dash.get and change-case.

Exmaple:
`getData(dataStructure, path, case, defaultValue);`

Formatting an entire data structure up front can be costly and cause performance issues

- https://lodash.com/docs/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/change-case